# correct way to inherit method with 1 correction

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I experimented a little bit OOP in python, while doing homework on data structures and I have some troubles with understanding how to correct inherit some method with corrections.

So, I have:

```
class BinarySearchTree(object):
    # snipped
    def _insert(self, key, val):
        prevNode = None
        currentNode = self.root
        while currentNode:
            prevNode = currentNode
            if key < currentNode.key:
                currentNode = currentNode.leftChild
            else:
                currentNode = currentNode.rightChild

        if key < prevNode.key:                      
            prevNode.leftChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.leftChild)            
        else:                                       
            prevNode.rightChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.rightChild)
    # snipped
```

And:

```
class RBTree(BinarySearchTree): 
    # snipped
    def _insert(self, key, val):
        prevNode = None
        currentNode = self.root
        while currentNode:
            prevNode = currentNode  
            prevNode.size += 1 # The only difference is in this line
            if key < currentNode.key:
                currentNode = currentNode.leftChild
            else:
                currentNode = currentNode.rightChild

        if key < prevNode.key:                      
            prevNode.leftChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.leftChild)            
        else:                                       
            prevNode.rightChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.rightChild)
    # snipped
```

And there is my question: is there smart way to inherit this method and realise this 1 difference(`prevNode.size += 1`) without copying whole inherited function code?

*P.S.: sorry for my bad english.*

UPD: Now I cannot choose between Scott's and CAB's solutions...

Comment: No. This is how you'll have to do it. If you were only modifying the node once, that would be one thing, but because it's in a loop, you'll have to just reimplement the method.

Comment: You could have `prevNode.size += self.something` and set that appropriately (to `0` by default).

Comment: For [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), code in your tree class should manage the tree, not fiddle in the nodes themselves.  A good way to do this is the Visitor design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `prevNode` is also a `BTree` or `RBTree`, you could add another method, say 'updateSize`, and include the line

```
prevNode.updateSize()
```

In `BTree`, this would do nothing.  But if you make `RBTree` a subclass of `BTRee`, you could override this method to add 1 to the node's size.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly elegant, but you could do something like this:

```
class BinarySearchTree(object):
    def _insert(self, key, val, update=False):
       prevNode = None
       currentNode = self.root
        while currentNode:
            prevNode = currentNode
            if update:
                prevNode.size += 1
            if key < currentNode.key:
                currentNode = currentNode.leftChild
            else:
                currentNode = currentNode.rightChild

        if key < prevNode.key:                      
            prevNode.leftChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.leftChild)            
        else:                                       
            prevNode.rightChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
            self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.rightChild)
    # snipped  

class RBTree(BinarySearchTree): 
    # snipped

    def _insert(self, key, val):
        super(RBTree, self)._insert(self, key, val, update=True)
```

I don't really like that, because it has code in your `BinarySearchTree` class to update an instance variable that doesn't exist except in the derived `RBTree` class, but since that part of the code shouldn't ever get executed for a `BinarySearchTree` instance, you shouldn't encounter a `NameError`...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion using the Visitor design pattern.

In this pattern, you're writing a visitor method than knows specifically what needs to be done with each node visited.

We'll change the base class to add a visitor capability;

```
class BinarySearchTree(object):
# snipped
def _insert(self, key, val, visitor=None):   # Change here
    prevNode = None
    currentNode = self.root
    while currentNode:
        prevNode = currentNode
        if visitor: visitor(prevNode)       # Change here
        if key < currentNode.key:
            currentNode = currentNode.leftChild
        else:
            currentNode = currentNode.rightChild

    if key < prevNode.key:                      
        prevNode.leftChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
        self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.leftChild)            
    else:                                       
        prevNode.rightChild = self.Node(key, val, parent=prevNode)
        self.updateNodeProperties(prevNode.rightChild)
# snipped
```

Now your second class;

```
class RBTree(BinarySearchTree): 
# snipped
def _insert(self, key, val):
    visitor = lambda node: node.size += 1
    super(RBTree, self)._insert(self, key, val, visitor)
# snipped
```

Comment: Big thx, but while you were writing the answer, I did the same thing because of your comment to the original post :)